# Writing unicode strings in c++ to sqlite DB

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm currently building a manager game using sqlite and c++. I've found tutorials on covering almost every area needed to create my game but a minor issue has been bugging me for ages.

when I write a string in c++ for example "Andreas Klöden" and uses it with a sqlite statement to insert the data in my sqlite DB the special characters with umlaut ö are lost, this goes for many european names like Léfevre, Würth etc.

I have searched for an answer at it seems that c++ strings are in ANSII or something like that. Somehow I should write unicode strings instead to avoid the issue shown below:

http://imageshack.dk//viewimage.php?file=/imagesfree/0Ej53884.png

does anyone know how to write unicode strings in c++ so I can export/import the correct data from the sqlite DB?

Comment: have you looked at std::wstring?

Comment: There's no such thing as ANSII; it looks like a cross between [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii) (a 7-bit character set) and [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (Microsoft's misnomer for an 8-bit character set similar to Latin-1). There are a number of different ways to represent Unicode strings. [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) is generally best, but Windows likes to use [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Answer (score 4):

SQLite "supports" UTF-8 (the quotes are here because basically UTF8 uses only ASCII characters so there is nothing to "support" actually). So one of the best (and also backwards-compatible) ways is to use the UTF-8 encoding. wchar_t support in SQLite is also present, but there is only one reason to use it: if you code already depends on the wchar_t.

Read this if "UTF-8" is not a familiar topic: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

The call to C API

```
sqlite_exec(db_conn, "insert somevalue into sometable values(\"utf encoded string\""), NULL, NULL, "error");
```

would do the job.

The actual conversion can be done manually if you have to support only limited amount of codepages or use the ICU library for full support. There are also libs like http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

CodeProject also has a lot of UTF-8 sample codes:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14637/UTF-8-With-C-in-a-Portable-Way

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5281/UTF-8-Encoding-and-Decoding

etc.

Comment: thanks a lot I'll give it a go with the suggestions and return with the results :)

Comment: You're welcome. I do not post unchecked answers and believe me I also have troubles with my native cyrillic alphabet for years so UTF-8 was a great relief :)

Comment: allright I've managed to create a sqlite insert statement as a const wchar_t command.
next problem when i write the sqlite command in c++:
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlInsertTest, NULL, NULL, &error);

it says that it can't convert from const char to const wchar_t, so somehow it expects a standard char and not the special wchar_t. Do you know an equal sqlite function for the wchar_t?

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg25251.html   Bottom line - use the prepare/step/finalize API in case of wchar_t. Exec() is legacy.

Answer (score -1):

CppSqlite3U has been developed for the purpose of being a wrapper for sqlite3, which doesn't support UNICODE. [CppSqlite3U](http://naughter.com/sqlitewrappers.html) can be used as the front end to your UNICODE calls.